# Sort a list of words alphabetically without using sort()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to sort a list of words alphabetically but without using sort().

Something like this:

```
list = ['shrek', 'shark', 'ship']
```

Would have to look like this:

```
newList = ['shark', 'ship', 'shrek']
```

Comment: Have you read https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-basics  ?

Comment: btw Please don't use names like `list` for your variables. These are built-in names and could cause trouble later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:-

```
newList = sorted(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

```
lst = ['shrek','shark','ship']

lst.sort()

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['shark', 'ship', 'shrek']
```

If you only need the sorted list, as in, you won't have to use the original list after sorting,

`list.sort()` if more efficient than `list = sorted(list)`.

Comment: Here question is without sort/sorted function.

Comment: @panchanan Oh dear, I see that the question got edited to say "with using sort" after we answered.